Bloomberg BLPAPI, only returns high and low during init paint
question: How to Continuously Receive High and Low Prices for USD/JPY from Bloomberg API? Currently only receive this information from the init paint messages from bloomberg, subsequently I only get the bid and ask (offer) returned.
Overview:
Hi everyone,
I'm working on a real-time financial data application using the Bloomberg API, and I've run into a bit of a snag. While I can receive continuous updates for bid and ask prices, the high and low prices only seem to come through during the initial subscription response. I need these high and low prices to update continuously along with the bid and ask prices.
Here's a simplified version of my current implementation for subscribing to USD/JPY data:
from blpapi import SubscriptionList, SessionOptions, Session

def create_session():
    session_options = SessionOptions()
    session_options.setServerHost('localhost')
    session_options.setServerPort(8194)
    session = Session(session_options)
    session.start()
    session.openService('//blp/mktdata')
    return session

def subscribe_to_data(session):
    subscription_list = SubscriptionList()
    subscription_list.add('USDJPY Curncy', ["BID","ASK","HIGH","LOW", ""] blpapi.CorrelationId('USDJPY'))
    session.subscribe(subscription_list)

def process_message(msg):
    if msg.hasElement('BID') and msg.hasElement('ASK'):
        bid = msg.getElementAsFloat('BID')
        ask = msg.getElementAsFloat('ASK')
    if msg.hasElement('HIGH') and msg.hasElement('LOW'):
        high = msg.getElementAsFloat('HIGH')
        low = msg.getElementAsFloat('LOW')
        
    # Update application state with new values
    update_gui(bid, ask, high, low)

def main():
    session = create_session()
    subscribe_to_data(session)
    while True:
        event = session.nextEvent()
        for msg in event:
            process_message(msg)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

The Problem:
I only receive high and low prices during the initial subscription response (event type init paint / Summary), but not in subsequent real-time updates. I want to ensure that high and low prices are included in every update for USD/JPY or at least when the high and low changes throughout the day.
The Question:
What changes do I need to make to my subscription or data handling to continuously receive high and low prices along with bid and ask prices in every real-time update?
Additional Context:
I'm using the Bloomberg Python API (blpapi). Any advice or examples on how to properly configure the subscription to ensure continuous high and low price updates would be greatly appreciated rather than currently I just receive this during the init paint message I get from BLPAPI
Thanks in advance for your help!
SOLVED thanks to @DS_London

import blpapi

class RealTimePricing:

    def __init__(self, security="EUR Curncy", interval=0.5):
        self.security = security
        self.interval = interval
        self.session = None

    def start_session(self):
        options = blpapi.SessionOptions()
        options.setServerHost("localhost")
        options.setServerPort(8194)

        self.session = blpapi.Session(options)

        if not self.session.start():
            print("Failed to start session.")
            return False

        if not self.session.openService("//blp/mktdata"):
            print("Failed to open //blp/mktdata")
            return False

        return True

    def subscribe(self):
        subscription_list = blpapi.SubscriptionList()
        subscription_list.add(self.security, "BID,ASK,HIGH,LOW,PRICE_HIGH_RT,HIGH_TDY,PX_HIGH_ASK_RT,PX_HIGH_BID_RT", 
                              f"interval={self.interval}", blpapi.CorrelationId(self.security))
        self.session.subscribe(subscription_list)

    def process_message(self, msg):
        fields = ["HIGH", "LOW", "PRICE_HIGH_RT", "HIGH_TDY", "PX_HIGH_ASK_RT", "PX_HIGH_BID_RT"]
        for field in fields:
            if msg.hasElement(field):
                value = msg.getElementAsFloat(field)
                print(f"{field}: {value}")

    def event_loop(self):
        try:
            while True:
                event = self.session.nextEvent(500)
                if event.eventType() in [blpapi.Event.SUBSCRIPTION_DATA, blpapi.Event.SUBSCRIPTION_STATUS]:
                    for msg in event:
                        self.process_message(msg)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print("Exiting...")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pricing = RealTimePricing()
    if pricing.start_session():
        pricing.subscribe()
        pricing.event_loop()


The BLPAPI documentation states:

Core Developer Guide (p. 34): Initial messages include all fields; subsequent messages may only include some.
Service-Schema-Reference-Guide (p. 83): "HIGH" and "LOW" fields represent daily high and low prices.

Despite this, I never see updates for high and low prices throughout the day for active pairs like USDJPY. Is this expected, or could there be an issue with my subscription or message handling?

Can you explain a bit what high and low will be when you call nextEvent? What high and low are you expecting in this context. High and low of that minute hour day week?

Regardless I think what you are looking for is something like BarRequest or TickRequest. Where bar/tick represent start time and end time.
You should only get high and low if there is any time related field passed to api.
Logically events shoudnt contain high and low.
Look at this example for reference: https://github.com/msitt/blpapi-python/blob/ec021c459196f5a5e50e2654897d839bc2d0c912/examples/demoapps/snippets/requestresponse/IntradayBarRequests.py

Thanks @Poojan I'm expecting the High and Low to be of that day, as per the bloomberg Terminal gui. It is correct as of init paint, however throughout the day as usdjpy or eurusd make new highs the high is not updated. Unless I'm missing a message due to a timeout issue in my code. Have you managed to achieve getting high and lows updating throuout the day before for other securities or in another example. Thanks for your time and help. I'll add extra code to my question

There are a few variations on HIGH:  HIGH_TDY, PX_HIGH_ASK_RT,PX_HIGH_BID_RT,PRICE_HIGH_RT. Also you can specify an interval on the subscription options when adding  a subscription (eg 0.5 in seconds). This will send you a frame every 0.5 seconds, which generally contains all the fields that have changed. I tested this with EUR Curncy, and the frames contained HIGH and PRICE_HIGH_RT as the market hit new highs.

Key issue

try:
    high, low = msg.getElementAsFloat("HIGH"), msg.getElementAsFloat("LOW")
except Exception:
    pass


Was attempting to access both values from he same message so it only works during init paint
Instead subsequent messages come from first with high for example and then low, so it would fail as it's attempting to access both at the same time and fails
Also above code block works perfectly, thanks to @DS_London
